# GUI + listen to specific key on the keyboard

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener

I have a GUI program in Java, but I want to make it possible to press the 'q' key on the keyboard to exit the program. My class implements the KeyListener interface, and this is my keyPressed method:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have also added the keyListener to my JFrame:

```
frame.addKeyListener(this);
```

What is it that I miss in my code to make this work? I have to JPanels inside my JFrame, do I have to add the keyListener to these also?

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For a `KeyListener` to work, the component to which it is added must both be focusable and have focus.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without using KeyBindings? I have set the JFrame to focusable now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: *"Is there no way to do this without using KeyBindings?"*  You say that like you're allergic to key bindings.  Why ***not*** use them?

Comment: Ok, I tried with KeyBindings and it worked, you were right :) It just looked very complicated. Just one question, why can't I use KeyBindings with JFrame?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  *"why can't I use KeyBindings with JFrame?"*  DYM "..`KeyListener` with frame"?

Comment: No, key bindings. I tried frame.getInPutMap(....) and frame.getActionMap(...) but this didn't work. When I used it with a JPanel, it worked perfectly.

Comment: `getInPutMap` and `getActionMap` are defined for `JComponent` (and its subclasses). `JFrame` is a subclass of `Window` instead (see [`Container`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html).

Comment: Also, it seems that a better way to do what you want is to use a menu bar with `q` being a shortcut for the `Quit` option.